# Trying to remove an ID via CSS

Tags: css

I have an ID that I need to modify via an extension called Stylus (Chrome). Basically, I need it to display nothing, as the website uses an element I do not want to see. In any case, when I place:

```
#7821s3s693453355sdb487326acb {display: none !important}
```

It still displays it. I also tried removing the class. I was wondering, is it possible that certain elements like buttons (which this one is specifically) still be displayed, regardless of whether or not we want it displayed or not?

I tried removing other things for testing, and those worked. Just not THAT specific one. I dunno if it's because the ID is extremely long, or something else I'm not seeing.

Comment: Just open the dev tools, inspect the element and find out why

Comment: Check your devtools to see which CSS rules are applied and in what order.

Comment: Your id is not a valid identifier (it is starting with a digit, which is not allowed). [4.1.3 Characters and case](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters)

Comment: @lukas.j I didn't create the website. Tell them that lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```css
*[id="7821s3s693453355sdb487326acb"] {display: none !important}
```

Comment: That worked! Sorry someone downvoted your answer. I upvoted it. Thanks!